# REST API Create Group TFS 2018 update 3

Tags: rest, tfs

As stated in the title, I try to create or even list the Groups of the server.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/graph/groups/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) explains with the example command to list all groups:

```
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/graph/groups?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

I don't know how to get to this preview version, because Version 4.1 quotes a 404 error.

So it seems it isn't available in the latest official version? Has somebody got other experiences?

Regards.

Comment: Additionally I found a [mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#api-and-tfs-version-mapping)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API you mentioned is for Azure DevOps only.

For on-premise TFS 2018 update3, you can use below REST API:

**To list groups:**

```
GET http://tfs2018u3:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/Groups?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

**To create a group:**

```
POST http://tfs2018u3:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_api/_identity/ManageGroup?api-version=4.1-preview.1

Content-Type: application/json

Request Body:

{"name":"Test1024","description":"test1023"}
```

[image]

Comment: ty, do you have any documentation from MC for this?